# Maven, GWT, Google Eclipse plugin, can not copy jar to WEB-INF/lib when dependency project is war

Tags: java, gwt, maven, google-eclipse-plugin

I have a maven project, project A depends on project B, A is a GWT web project, in project A's pom:

```
    <dependency>    
            <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>             
            <artifactId>b</artifactId>          
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>   
    </dependency>
```

and B project's packaging is jar. Everything works fine till now. But i need to add some integrated test on project B, which need to turn project B's packaging to war, so it can setup a web environment that i can run the integrated test cases.

Then when i run/debug project A using Google Eclipse plugin, project B's jar never copied to project A's target/A-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib, and runtime class not foundexception thrown. 
My questions is how to solve problem like this, i need the integrated testcases in B and i also would like to debug in project A. 
Any help are appreciated.

Comment: After reading more carefully about http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html and http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/plugin-info.html I thought i have come up with a solution: leave project B as jar packaging as it should be, then bind maven-war-plugin's exploded goal to maven package lifecycle, then when installing project B, it create a exploded war directory just before running integrated tests even it is not a war project. And also thanks to the people who give solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading more carefully about [http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/plugin-info.html) and http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/plugin-info.html
I thought i have come up with a solution: leave project B as jar packaging as it should be, then bind maven-war-plugin's **exploded** goal to maven **package** lifecycle, then when installing project B, it create a exploded war directory just before running integrated tests even it is not a war project. And also thanks to the people who give solutions.

Answer (score 1):

hmm, not sure I fully understand-- but I would suggest packaging `B` into jar to be used by `A`, and then independently package and deploy `B` as a `WAR`.

This separation will allow both `A` and `B.WAR` to depend on `B.jar` as opposed to `A` depending on `B.WAR`.